# Hive query to print the collect_set value for multiple entries and not to print if the entry is once

Tags: arrays, hive, hiveql

My table in hive:

```
Group1  |       sibling

=====================

ad3jkfk            4

ad3jkfk            4

ad3jkfk            2

fkjh43f            1

fkjh43f            8

fkjh43f            8

rjkhd93            7

rjkhd93            4

rjkhd93            7

abcd45             1

defg63             1
```

Expected result:

```
Group1   |       sibling

===========================

ad3jkfk          4,4,2

fkjh43f          1,8,8 

rjkhd93          7,4,7
```

Answer (score 0):

`collect_set` produces an array of distinct values. For ad3jkfk it will produce `4,2`, not `4,4,2`

If you want `4,4,2`, then use `collect_list()`.

To filter arrays with more than 1 element, use `size()` function:

```
select Group1, concat_ws(',',sibling_list)  sibling --Concatenate array to string delimited w comma like in your example
from
(
select Group1, collect_list(sibling) sibling_list --get the list
  from mytable
 group by Group1
)s
where size(sibling_list)>1 --filter
```